Widest range possible 2x11 GRX?
Shimano GRX 2x11 comes as 48/31 crank and 11/34 cassette covering 4.36 to 0.91 range. Are there options to widen this range? Quick search shows that it is only 48/31 and no-one makes 10-36 cassettes in 11 spd.

Unless you use it for high-level road race sprints, you should not really need a 10 in the back with a 48 in the front on a gravel bike. 11-36 should be doable.  There is also the 46-30 option available for the crankset for lower gears. This guy uses 11-42 in the back https://bikepacking.com/gear/wide-range-grx-2x11/  Insisting on the 10T small cog will limit you strongly and may require a new freehub.

Sunrace make both 11-36 and 10-42 11-speed cassettes, but you're right, no 10-36.  However they do make 11-40, which is almost exactly the same range, just shifted a tiny bit

@VladimirFГероямслава I've got 30/46 × 11-36 with an FSA crankset, 105 derailleurs (used slightly out of spec) and Sunrace cassette.  But I need to test it with a new chain rather than one that was surprisngly worn

Related question: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/92277/having-a-double-chainring-and-11-42-cassette-on-a-grx-11-speed-goat-link-tanpan?rq=1

@Vladimir F Героям слава Еhe question stems from experience. I have a free-hub that fits both Shimano and XD/XDR cassettes, so not a problem. Thx for 11-40 video from bikepacking, at least lower range seems to be easily extendable. Слава Україні.
